# How to work with SOAP web service and it's XML in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I want to call a function of a web service in my project developed by PHP. This is my code:

```
$wsdl="http://x.x.x.x:8090/charge/services/Amount?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl) or die("Error");

$chargeAmountArray  = array('UserIdentifier' => $number ,
                            'data' => array(
                            'description' => array("Channel=test|".$Origin),
                            'currency' => NULL,
                            'code' => $code),
                            'refrence' => $refcode);

$header = new SoapHeader('servicekey', $servicekey);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$res = $client->__call('chargeAmount',$chargeAmountArray); 

return $res->return;
```

I have seen my xml code with tcpdump and it is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/payment/amount_charging/v4_0/local" xmlns:ns2="servicekey">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:e0ce5ed56d7c4d60/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:chargeAmount/>
        <param1>
            <item>
                <key>description</key>
                <value>yChannel=test|30733</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key>currency</key>
                <value/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key>code</key>
                <value>MOBDY</value>
            </item>
        </param1>
        <param2>1PN1mROoZop2hAy</param2>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you see the `UserIdentifier` is not passed and the `refrence` parameter has no name in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors here.

The [constructor signature for the `SoapHeader` class](http://php.net/manual/en/soapheader.construct.php) shows the first parameter is a namespace declaration, which it doesn't appear you are setting.

Also, [`SoapClient::__call()` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php); instead you should call the method directly:

```
$res = $client->chargeAmount($chargeAmountArray);
```

`SoapClient::__call()` expects parameters in an array with key "parameters", which you are not providing.

Finally, you should be doing some error checking with `try`/`catch` in case the connection can't be made for whatever reason.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by this sentence : The constructor signature for the SoapHeader class shows the first parameter is a namespace declaration, which it doesn't appear you are setting. I have used  `SoapClient::__call()` since I have used `nusoap`. Also I used `try/catch` and call function in this way `$res = $client->__call('chargeAmount',array('parameters'=>$chargeAmountArray)); ` and I get this error:  `Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] unknown`

Comment: The constructor is the function that's called when you use `new SoapHeader()`. You're calling it wrong. And don't use `SoapClient__call()`, it's deprecated.